# Is the [radio] tag necessary?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

There are [18 questions](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/radio) tagged [radio](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/radio).  I am proposing deleting it, as it is largely redundant and confused with other tags.

- 10 are also tagged [radio-communication](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/radio-communication).
- 2 more are tagged [radio-astronomy](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/radio-astronomy) or [radio-telescope](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/radio-telescope).

Questions with remaining tags that seem sufficient:

- [What is required to make GPS signals available indoors?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/35235/26446) [gps](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gps)
- [Could we use a narrow paradigm, say laser, to get info faster from New Horizons? (With a moon base.)](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/33287/26446) [communication](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/communication) [laser](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/laser)
- [Was it a "Soviet military satellite not in any of the catalogs?"](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/18049/26446) [artificial-satellite](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/artificial-satellite) [military](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/military) [seti](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/seti)

Propose replacing [communication](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/communication) to [radio-communication](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/radio-communication):

- [Apollo communication between the Earth and Moon](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/12264/26446) [the-moon](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-moon) [nasa](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nasa) [apollo-program](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/apollo-program) [communication](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/communication)

Propose adding [radio-communication](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/radio-communication):

- [How much power does the Voyager radio dish draw?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/10014/26446) [voyager](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/voyager) [power](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/power) [dish](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dish)

Not really about radio (delete the tag):

- [Looking for a live audio-only stream of NASA TV or JSC/ISS loops](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/50879/26446)

Answer (score 3):

I've gone ahead and adjusted tagging on:

- [Was it a "Soviet military satellite not in any of the catalogs?"](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/18049/12102)
- [Is the recently discovered VLF-induced radiation barrier in any way important or useful?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/21584/12102)

Everything else stated at the moment seems okay to me.

Answer (score 1):

I can agree it with the condition that **it does not destroy content**.

All the removed [radio](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/radio) tags should be replaced by a more specific one ([radio-astronomy](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/radio-astronomy), [radio-communication](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/radio-communication), and so on). So it is not deletion, but improvement (more specific tag -> more information). Or any edit is okay, if the total information content (measured in bits) grows and does not decrease.

Answer (score 0):

I have gone ahead and appropriately re-tagged all 18 questions.  The tag is now empty.  Could a mod please delete it and set this meta-post [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)?

Future questions should use [radio-communication](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/radio-communication), [radio-astronomy](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/radio-astronomy), or [radio-telescope](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/radio-telescope) as appropriate.

Comment: Mods can't delete tags. They are deleted automatically when they are not used on any questions.